# Parent Node Stalling On MPI_Barrier

Tags: c, mpi

I'm new to MPI, and I am having some trouble implementing mpirun on a cluster of Mac OS X nodes running snow leopard.  The issue that I'm having involves `MPI_Barrier()`.  I have a simple function shown below that works fine.  However, when I add an `MPI_Barrier()` command at the end of the conditional, the parent node stalls.  One of the processors moves past the barrier command, while the other one stays stuck.  I was hoping someone could give me a quick workaround, or maybe suggest some way in which my network environment is preventing the command from functioning properly.

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int me, np, q, sendto;
    double t0, t1;
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    t0 = MPI_Wtime();
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&np);
    MPI_Commm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&me);
    if (np%2 == 1) return 0;
    if (me%2 == 1) {sendto = me - 1;}
    else {sendto = me + 1;}
    if (me%2 == 0) {
        MPI_Send(&me, 1, MPI_INT, sendto, me, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPIRecv(&q, 1, MPI_INT, sendto, sendto, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    } else {
        MPI_Recv(&q, 1, MPI_INT, sendto, sendto, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
        MPI_Send(&me,1,MPI_INT,sendto,me,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    printf("Send %d to proc %d, received %d from proc %d\n",me,sendto,q,sendto);
    t1 = MPI_Wtime();
    printf("Timing is %g",t1-10);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than fixing a few typos, I get your code to work without issue. I'm using openmpi and gnu c compiler on an IBM cluster. I'm not sure where you put the barrier. Have I guess correctly?

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include "stdio.h"

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
int me, np, q, sendto;
double t0, t1;
MPI_Status status;
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
t0 = MPI_Wtime();
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&np);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&me);
if (np%2 == 1) {
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
if (me%2 == 1) {sendto = me - 1;}
else {sendto = me + 1;}
if (me%2 == 0) {
  MPI_Send(&me, 1, MPI_INT, sendto, me, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  MPI_Recv(&q, 1, MPI_INT, sendto, sendto, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
} else {
  MPI_Recv(&q, 1, MPI_INT, sendto, sendto, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
  MPI_Send(&me,1,MPI_INT,sendto,me,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
printf("Send %d to proc %d, received %d from proc %d\n",
   me,sendto,q,sendto);
t1 = MPI_Wtime();
printf("Timing is %g\n",t1-t0);
MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is the exactly what the program that stalls looks like (with the exception of the Finalize statement in the first conditional).  My barrier is in the same place as shown in your code.

Comment: I also got this program to work.  Try cutting and pasting this text and trying that.  I suspect that there is some typo that you are missing.